# Jquery parse custom xml

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I have an xml like

```
<contact>
    <name>
        <firstname>Ravindra</firstname>
    </name>
    <name>
        <firstname>Marya</firstname>
        <lastname>suthar</lastname>
    </name>
</contact>
```

When I applied find function "firstname" works fine but last mane connected with first "name" section.

I m doing something

```
var MyName=$(xml).find("firstname").eq(0).text()+" "+$(xml).find("lastname").eq(0).text();
```

Where result I m getting "Ravindra Suthar" but result should be "Ravindra "

Please let me know how to I can make this possible without "if else".

Answer (score 0):

you can put it all in a one liner, but for clarity:

```
var $firstName=$(xml).find("firstname").eq(0);
var firstName = $firstName.text();
var lastName = $firstName.siblings("lastname").text();
var MyName = firstName +" "+lastName;
```

With jquery's nice `siblings` method, we search for the last name only at the level of that first name we previously found.

Ah, what the hell, the one liner:

```
var MyName = $(xml).find("firstname").eq(0).text() +" "+$(xml).find("firstname").eq(0).siblings("lastname").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

eq() finds the first matched element in the set. so you look for all lastnames and get the first in the set, which is suthar.

You'll have to find the first 'name' then select the first and lastnames:

```
$(xml).find('name:nth-child(1)>firstname').text() + " " + $(xml).find('name:nth-child(1)>lastname').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find("name").each(function () {     
var MyName = $(this).find("firstname").text() + " " + $(this).find("lastname").text();
     alert(MyName);
});
```

first alert -> Ravindra

second alert-> Marya suthar